# Restoring the dependencies of a NuGet package in packages.config

Tags: nuget, packages.config

How can I restore a NuGet package and all of its dependencies without specifying each of them individually?

Say I have a `packages.config` file that is not associated with a `.csproj` or `.sln` file.

It contains one package ("PackageA") and this package has its own dependency ("PackageB").

Running `nuget.exe install packages.config` will install PackageA, but not PackageB.

Is there a way for `nuget.exe` to install PackageA **AND** its dependency PackageB?

---

Below is a reproducible example.

I have a manually generated `packags.config` that references Moq, [a package that has two dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.18.4#dependencies-body-tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" />
</packages>
```

I downloaded nuget.exe from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads). When I run `nuget.exe install packages.config`, only `Moq.4.18.4` is installed, without any of the dependencies. I see the same result when I run `nuget.exe restore packages.config -PackageDirectory .`.

Contrast this with running `nuget.exe install moq`, which WILL install Moq and all of its dependencies.

---

Per Microsoft's documentation on [dependency resolution with `packages.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#dependency-resolution-with-packagesconfig), I think that the dependencies need to be explicitly specified. This suggests that I cannot manually create a `packages.config` file that only references "Moq" or "PackageA" for example. I could use this `packages.config` as input to a script that calls nuget.exe install for each package (and thus installing dependencies automatically that way), but that feels a little clunky...

---

[More evidence](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6335) suggesting I am out of luck.

Comment: `nuget restore`?

Comment: No, I get the same outcome -- only PackageA

Comment: Are you sure the package / command is correct? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore), when used with a packages.config file, _Restore packages listed in the file, resolving and installing dependencies_

Comment: I've added a reproducible example that demonstrates this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the edits to my question, I was unable to find a way to restore dependencies that are NOT directly specific in a `packages.config` file. My advice would be to only restore from a file like this if you are ready to specify additional dependencies manually; otherwise, use `nuget install` for *specific* package targets or use a `csproj` file where you only need to specify the direct dependencies.